# Create new list in nested list C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

Anyone know how to add new list into another list, the new list cannot be predefined.

For example, after get user input, I will do the following

```
List<List<string>> ListA = new List<List<string>>();

foreach (List<string> subList in ListA)
{
     foreach (var value in subList)
     {
          if(value != INPUT)
          {
                // ListA needs to creates a new list with value INPUT
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do, to be honest. Are you absolutely sure you don't need something like a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `ListA.Add(new List<string> { "INPUT" })`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you cannot modify collection that you're currently enumerating use eg. `ToArray()`:

```
foreach (List<string> subList in ListA.ToArray())
{
    foreach (var value in subList)
    {
           if(value != INPUT)
           (
              ListA.Add(new List<string>() { INPUT });
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but I don't think that this is what OP wants. I think that he wants to add a new list to `ListA` if there is no INPUT in any sublist. OP please clarify what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `linq` to do this:

include the namespace:

```
using System.Linq;
```

And try this:

```
var result = ListA.Select(x => x.Where(k => k != INPUT).ToList()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<List<string>> ListA = new List<List<string>>();
List<List<string>> ListsToAdd = new List<List<string>>();

foreach (List<string> subList in ListA)
{
    foreach (var value in subList)
    {
           if(value != INPUT)
           (
              List<string> list = new List<string>();
              list.Add(INPUT);
              ListsToAdd.Add(list);
           }
    }
}
ListA.AddRange(ListsToAdd);
```